# Why isn't toLocaleDateString working in react-native (Android)?

Tags: javascript, date, react-native

For some strange reasons, `toLocaleDateString` isn't working properly in react-native. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. For the following code,

```
const dateString = this.state.date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
            weekday: 'short',
            day: 'numeric',
            month: 'long',
            year: 'numeric',
        });
```

Sometimes I get just `07/17/2018` and sometimes regular output. Now I can implement it myself or use `moment.js` or something like that. I want to know why this is behaving like that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

React Native used JavaScriptCore engine in non-debug mode & it doesn't work well with dates, but work during debug because it use chrome V8 engine while debugging.

So it is better to use [moment](https://momentjs.com/) or [XDate](https://arshaw.com/xdate/) JavaScript library.

Comment: It seems, I'm also having issue with sorting, can you point to some resource where  all the limitations of  `JavaScriptCore` are documented? Or any idea how to debug with `JavaScriptCore`?

Comment: and how do you do to LocaleDateString with moment ?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa can you explain your question a bit more.

Comment: How can you replace this feature in Android

Comment: I downvoted because this doesn't answer the question with a solution specific to the platform..it redirect to a library that doesn't seems to have an equivalent.

Comment: `moment` is no longer being developed. I recommend using `luxon`.

Answer (score 9):

I am currently on `"react-native": "~0.63.3",` and have the same issue when using toLocaleDateString. Here is what fixed it for me:

In my android/app/build.gradle file I replaced the following line

```
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+' //remove this - it might be something else depending on your react-native version, try to look in your build.gradle file for similar comment I posted below in the picture
```

with

```
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+' // add this
```

The solution was found here: https://github.com/react-community/jsc-android-buildscripts#international-variant

and in my build.gradle file there is a comment from react-native, that describes that issue

[image]

Comment: Not a fan of this making the build larger, but just confirming that this did bring functionality in line with the iOS coutnerpart

Answer (score 4):

[SDushan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51400372/3395342) is right. It is better to use either Moment or XDate.

But I chose to write a small function instead of importing the whole library.

```
function getDateString(date) {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios')
        return date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
            weekday: 'short',
            day: 'numeric',
            month: 'long',
            year: 'numeric',
        });
    else {

        var
            dayOfWeek = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
            monthName = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                         "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
            utc = date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000,
            US_time = utc + (3600000 * -4),
            US_date = new Date(US_time);

        return dayOfWeek[US_date.getDay()-1] + ", " + monthName[US_date.getMonth()] +
               " " + US_date.getDate() + ", " + US_date.getFullYear();
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (Platform.OS === 'ios')` please no, do not do that. Ever. After 20 odd years of web development you're reverting to sniffing platforms? Noooooooo. And why are you doing anything with host timezone offset? *toLocaleString* uses the host offset unless the [*timeZone* option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) is used, which the OP isn't. And even if you want to adjust to another offset, just use UTC methods and ignore the host offset altogether.

Comment: RobG in practice I found it convenient to use the platform test in a source. If you are confident to use the source in react native it saved a lot of Time and there are no downside. In theory,  I can't disagree. Reality is not theory.

Comment: @RobG `Platform.OS` checks are a necessary evil in react native. There's no way around it. In web development behavior is much more consistent across platforms than in react native, and in these cases Platform.OS is what you have to use to fix it

Comment: @ICW— *toLocaleString* is platform dependent, it can change any time the developers want to change it. Including platforms other than iOS. That's why using it to infer the format returned by *toLocaleString* is unreliable. If a particular format is required, the OP should format the string manually and not take a piecemeal approach via host attributes.

Answer (score 2):

I used moment like [SDushan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399551/why-isnt-tolocaledatestring-working-in-react-native-android/51400372#51400372) said, here is an example:

```
import i18n from '../i18n';

const moment = require('moment');

moment.locale('es', {
  months : 'enero_febrero_marzo_abril_mayo_junio_julio_agosto_septiembre_octubre_noviembre_diciembre'.split('_'),
  weekdays : 'domingo_lunes_martes_miercoles_jueves_viernes_sábado'.split('_'),
  relativeTime : {
      future : 'dentro de %s',
      past : 'hace %s',
      s : 'algunos segundos',
      m : 'un minuto',
      mm : '%d minutos',
      h : 'una hora',
      hh : '%d horas',
      d : 'un día',
      dd : '%d días',
      M : 'un mes',
      MM : '%d meses',
      y : 'un año',
      yy : '%d años'
  }
});

export const translateDate = date => {
    const currentLanguage = i18n.language;
    moment.locale(currentLanguage); // or moment.locale('es')
    const dateString = moment(date).format('dddd Do MMMM, YYYY');
    return dateString.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + dateString.slice(1)
}
```

Then you can use it in your component:

```
<View style={Styles().containerDate}>
     <Input
          inputContainerStyle={Styles().inputContainerStyle}
          inputStyle={Styles().inputText}
          editable={false}
          label={i18n.t(`${i18nConfinement}.startdate`)}
          placeholderTextColor={Styles().placeholder.color}
          value={translateDate(startDate)}
      />
      <Icon onPress={() => setShowStartDate(!showStartDate)} size={25} name={showStartDate ? 'calendar-check-o' : 'calendar'} color={Styles().icon.color} type='font-awesome' />
 </View>
```

[Here](https://www.sitepoint.com/managing-dates-times-using-moment-js/) is an article about how to manage dates using moment.js

Final result:

[image]

Comment: Im' not sure, what is moment.js doing? Seems to me you wrote the whole thing for only one language and one format. Let's say you want to support all the languages and date/time formats in the world, like does toLocaleDateString?

Comment: @Destal Yeah, I wrote it for one language, but the formats are not static, so it helps. That was the solution I found out at the time, cuz toLocaleDateString didn't work on Android.  Moment is used as a global object or state of languages so I can change from English to Spanish and get the formats I want.

Comment: Moment.js is effectively being deprecated: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Comment: The problem is, this is hard-coded locale. If the user configs a different locale or a different format in the system, how to detect that?

Answer (score -1):

i used it to get dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss format, worked well

```js
function addZero(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}

const convertUTCToLocalTime = (dateString) => {
  let date = new Date(dateString);
  const milliseconds = Date.UTC(
    date.getFullYear(),
    date.getMonth(),
    date.getDate(),
    date.getHours(),
    date.getMinutes(),
    date.getSeconds(),
  );
  const localTime = new Date(milliseconds);
  return localTime.getDate() + "." + localTime.getMonth() + "." + localTime.getFullYear() + " " +
    addZero(localTime.getHours()) + "." + addZero(localTime.getMinutes()) + "." + addZero(localTime.getSeconds());
};
```