# Issue with date format on iOS devices (vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, json, api, datetime

I'm currently building a weather app using vanilla JavaScript and am running into an issue with how my formatted date is displaying on my iPhone.

Here is my code:

```
dates = forecast.daily;
  let conditions = "";
  let minTemp = "";
  let maxTemp = "";
  let icon = "";
  let timestamp = "";
  let d = "";
  let formattedDate = "";

  let forecastInfoHTML = "";

  dates.forEach((day) => {
    conditions = day.weather[0].main;
    minTemp = Math.round(day.temp.min);
    maxTemp = Math.round(day.temp.max);
    icon = day.weather[0].icon;
    timestamp = day.dt;
    d = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
    formattedDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {
      dateStyle: "medium",
    })
      .format(d)
      .substr(0, 6);
```

This is how I want it to look (works fine on windows and mac browsers) - 'Feb 15': [Correct way I want this displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YESJZ.jpg)

This is how it is currently displaying on my iPhone - '2/15/2': [Incorrect display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPplO.jpg)

The JSON data uses a unix number, so I need to be able to change the unix to a date.

Comment: Is your `d` variable showing the same value on both platforms? If it is, it might be the Intl lib that is different on the two platforms.

Comment: @Mellet - I'm unsure how to check that the value for `b` variable on my iPhone?

Comment: What framework are you using? Should just be to do a console.log while having some debugging tool.

Comment: @Mellet I'm not using any framework - purely vanilla JS

Comment: The formats produced by *DateTimeFormat* are implementation dependent. If you want consistent formatting, do it yourself or use a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const date = new Date();
const month = date.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: 'short' });
const dateNum = date.getDate();
const prettyDate = `${month} ${dateNum}`;
console.log(prettyDate);
```

Comment: `toLocaleString` also not supported on react-native....

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399551/why-isnt-tolocaledatestring-working-in-react-native-android

Answer (score 1):

`Intl.DateTimeFormat.dateStyle` is NOT supported by IOS Safari... As you can see here: [MDN - Intl.DateTimeFormat - Compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat#browser_compatibility)

I suggest you explore a JS library made to handle dates and time more accurately: [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

This is the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) section about formating a date. You also will find all you need about manipulating it.

So your date formatting would look like this:

```js
// I don't know what is timestamp here...
//d = moment(timestamp * 1000);

// But this is equivalent to new Date()
// It creates a moment object with the current date/time
d = moment()

// And here is how to format it
console.log(d.format("MMM D"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```